# Number of combinations such that each pair of combinations has at most x elements in common?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I am doing research on the sense of smell and have a combinatorics problem:
I have 128 different odors (n) and I mix them in mixtures of 10 (r). There are 2.26846154e+14 different mixtures. What I want to know is: What is the size of the group of mixtures such that no mixture in the group shares more than 5 (k) odors with any other mixture in the group. I hope this makes sense. I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: This problem falls under the umbrella of [constant weight codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-weight_code). The parameters here are $n=128$, $w=10$, $d=10$. IIRC the best generic upper bound is the so called Johnson bound. [Lower bounds are also known](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/Andw.html), but that table doesn't reach anywhere near $n=128$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, such kind of questions are very hard to answer exactly, in particular, if the set of possibilities is so huge as in your case.
However, there is a standard method to derive an upper bound on the maximum size. I will compute this upper bound in this answer.

Your question can be reformulated: What is the maximum size of a set $X$ of mixtures, such that each set of $6$ odors is contained in at most one mixture in $X$?

We double count the set $Y$ of pairs $(T,B)$ where $T$ is a set of $6$ odors, and $B\in X$.

There are $\binom{128}{6}$ possibilities for $T$, and each $T$ is contained in at most one $B$. So $\#Y \leq \binom{128}{6}$.
On the other hand, there are $\#X$ possibilities for $B$, and each $B$ containes $\binom{10}{6}$ elements $T$.
So $\#Y = \#X\cdot\binom{10}{6}$.

This yields
$$ \#X \leq \frac{\binom{128}{6}}{\binom{10}{6}} \approx 1080219781813,33$$
so your group of mixtures cannot contain more than $1080219781813$ mixtures.

Comment: Thank you, this is very cool. Is there, by any chance, a method to calculate a lower bound, too? My experiments have shown that people can distinguish mixtures of 10 that differ in 5 or more odors. I want to derive from this a statement along the lines of "There are therefore at least X mixtures that have a different smell.", so a lower bound would help me make this conservatively.